# How can I use python to check if a site is written in WordPress?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, python-requests

I need to check several sites with Python to see if they are written in WordPress how can I do this? I use requests and BeautifulSoup4

I tried checking if the page has content with "wp-content" or "wordpress" but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More reliable approach is to analyze the HTML source code of the website and look for specific patterns or metadata that are commonly associated with WordPress installations. One such indicator is the presence of specific HTML tags or CSS classes that are commonly used by WordPress themes and plugins.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def check_wordpress(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    if soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'generator', 'content': 'WordPress'}) is not None:
        return True

    if soup.find('link', attrs={'rel': 'stylesheet', 'href': '/wp-content/'}) is not None:
        return True

    if soup.find('script', attrs={'src': '/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js'}) is not None:
        return True

    # If none of the above conditions match, it is likely not a WordPress site
    return False

# Example usage
url = 'https://example.com'
is_wordpress = check_wordpress(url)
print(f"The website at {url} is built with WordPress: {is_wordpress}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the website's HTML code and look for specific patterns or elements that are commonly present in WordPress sites. You first need to install `requests` package for Python using

```
pip install requests
```

Then you can use the following code to check whether the HTML of the site contains certain keywords that WordPress sites contain:

```
import requests
import re

def is_wordpress_site(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    html_code = response.text

    # Check for common WordPress patterns in HTML code
    patterns = [
        r'wp-content',
        r'wp-admin',
        r'wp-includes',
        r'wordpress\/'
    ]

    for pattern in patterns:
        if re.search(pattern, html_code, re.IGNORECASE):
            return True

    return False

def is_wordpress_site_wrapper(url):
    if(is_wordpress_site(url)):
        print(f'The website {url} is built using WordPress.')
    else:
        print(f'The website {url} is NOT built using WordPress')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    web1_url = 'https://time.com'   # Built using WordPress
    web2_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com' # Not built using WordPress
    is_wordpress_site_wrapper(web1_url)
    is_wordpress_site_wrapper(web2_url)
```